# Power Automate: How to generate autonumber for every batch of new items in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, autonumber

Here is the process that I wish to give autonumbers which i would like to call ATSUB# and ATT#: ATSUB#0001 and ATT#0001-01.

1. ATSUB Email is received and comes with attachments that ranges from 1 PDF and up.
2. I already setup a Sharepoint list with the column ATSUB# ATT# and Email ID and Attachment ID.
3. In this Sharepoint list, i would like the ATSUB# to increment per ATSUB email but the number of new items in the list depends on how many attachments there are in the ATSUB email.

Let's say these are the ATSUB Emails in Outlook:

1. ATSUB with 1 PDF on 3/1/2022
2. ATSUB with 2 PFDs on 3/2/2022
3. ATSUB with 2 PDFs on 3/2/2022

The resulting Sharepoint list should look like this:

| DATE | ATSUB# | ATT# |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3/1/2022 | ATSUB#0001 | ATT#0001-01 |
| 3/2/2022 | ATSUB#0002 | ATT#0002-01 |
| 3/2/2022 | ATSUB#0002 | ATT#0002-02 |
| 3/2/2022 | ATSUB#0003 | ATT#0003-01 |
| 3/2/2022 | ATSUB#0003 | ATT#0003-02 |

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Are you able to show us any sort of attempt you’ve made?

Comment: hello @Skin thanks for noticing my post. so far, i have already tried assigning autonumbering using the ID column. i set up a flow with when email arrives v3 > apply to each attachment > create item in the sharepoint list > update item based on ID. it is assigning autonumbering but gives each row 1 increment which is wrong since i need the atsub# to increment per email and not per attachment...

Comment: Yeah, so you’ll need to assign the relevant ID’s externally. My tip would be to get the item from the SP list that has the highest “ID” and then increment the external ID from there.